# C# format to thousand seperator

Tags: c#, format

I am trying to format user input to a thousand seperator format. I tried the code here, but it keeps breaking the application:

```
Amt.Text = String.Format("{0:0,0.00}", Convert.ToDouble(Amt));
```

So when the user inputs `3566412`, then it needs to convert automatically to `3,566,412`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert the control (named `Amt`) to a `double`, which is a bad idea since you want to convert the text of the control (`Amt.Text`). I would suggest to use a `decimal` since that is more precise and will not cause floating point issues:

```
Amt.Text = String.Format("{0:0,0.00}", Convert.ToDecimal(Amt.Text));
```

Another thing to consider is to use a control that can mask itself, so you don't need to replace the text yourself every time.

Comment: Thank you but when I try it that when and try to input 1500 it changes it to 5.001.00 . it does not keep the same order as I inputted the numbers

Comment: its within my textbox element

Comment: You mean an event handler? What event?

Comment: private void Amt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){  Amt.Text = String.Format("{0:0,0.00}", Convert.ToDecimal(Amt.Text));  }

Comment: And you see the cursor flashing when you type slowly and returning to the wrong position? This is why I recommend to use a control that does this for you.

Comment: how do i use a control?

Comment: I dont see the need for that

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [Standard Numeric Format Strings at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx)

Then you could do something like

```
Amt.Text = inputnumber.ToString("N");
```

Which will format 3566412 to 3,566,412.0

If you want to take it directly from the textbox, you could do something like this, which checks if the text can be parsed before setting the text

```
double result = 0;
if (double.TryParse(Amt.Text, out result)
{
    Amt.Text = result.ToString("N");
}
```

Comment: That will round the number, right? And what is `inputnumber`? How does it get the value from the control?

Comment: Thank you but when I try it that when and try to input 1500 it changes it to 5.001.00 . it does not keep the same order as I inputted the numbers

Comment: That sounds very strange, how did it happen?